# Достать определенный параметр из массива php

Tags: php, json

Добрый день!
Не могли бы подсказать как достать определенный параметр , допустим user из массива.В данный момент выводит весь массив. Спасибо

```html
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ib3aj",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic password",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678901"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$arr = json_decode($response);

foreach ($arr as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $key => $v2) {
        echo "$key : $v2 <br />";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: если вы часто работаете с json, вот такой код вам сильно жизнь облегчит - `echo (json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));`  - вот тут образец https://eval.in/908434

Comment: @splash58 банальный var_dump делает то же самое, а браузер даже стоит древовидную структуру, это прикинь сколько букв запоминать, нафиг оно надо?)

Comment: @Jean-Claude А че ж мне хром ничего не построил, когда я по ссылке перешел? xml - да. а json не умею

Comment: @splash58 у меня мазилка, а под хром плагин можно поставить, если такой функционал требуется.

Comment: @Jean-Claude про плагин я не подумал, но я себе для отладки так спечатываю, А чужие у меня не ходят, тока тут :)

Comment: @splash58 меня на все случаи жизни выручает var_dump, даже писать <pre> не надо, он в связке с phpstorm сам это как-то подставляет.

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$arr` у вас массив объектов, поэтому для доступа к свойству объекта используем стрелочку `->`

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    var_dump($arr[$index]->user);
}
```

Или так

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    var_dump($value->user);
}
```

Если декодировать json в ассоциативный массив

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);
```

То обращаться к элементам массива можно через квадратные скобки

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    var_dump($arr[$index]['user']);
    //или
    //var_dump($value['user']);
}
```

Comment: а где _"или так `$value['user']`"_ ? :)